# Neovim doesn't load packer.nvim

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

OS: `ArchLinux`

NeoVim: `8.3` (current 9.0 bugs when cursor reaches parethesis, so I downgraded it)

I tried to download packer.nvim as in [this repo](https://github.com/LunarVim/Neovim-from-scratch/tree/03-plugins).
I just copied the `lua/user/plugins.lua` to my config and required it from my `init.lua`. It certainly does clone it from GitHub, but then fails to packadd it. Neovim shows this error:

```
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/an/.config/nvim/lua/ledity/plugins.lua:15: Vim(packadd):E919:
 Directory not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/opt/packer.nvim"
```

If you relaunch nvim the mistake disappears, but packer loads neither automatically, no manually. Putting the package in `.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/opt/` doesn't help: nvim doesn't see it.

As I have understood, it should automatically load at start, as the package is stored in `.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/`, but it's not.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that I have set up `vim.opt.packpath` in my config incorrectly. Actually, there was no reason to set it at all. I deleted the line that sets it up and everything worked